# How to define same macro function based on different parameter

Tags: c++, macros, overloading

I have a function

```
void fun(int j, int i = 10);
```

I want to invoke the fun by a macro function.

```
#define fun1(x) fun(10)

#define fun1(x, y) fun(x, y)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to invoke the fun by a macro definition, or do you want to bind one parameter of the function so you can call it with 1 parameter?

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro here? In C++, it would be easier and more idiomatic to use inline functions instead. In general, if you state your *problem*, rather than just the imagined solution, you may get better help.

Comment: Yes I need that. I have not described whole scenario. Just a small portion of it where I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use a macro here? In C++, it would be easier and more idiomatic to use inline functions instead.

In general, if you state your *problem*, rather than just the imagined solution, you may get better help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload macros based on number of parameters, as you do functions.

You're better off just calling the function.

Comment: I have not described whole scenario. I need a functionality like this.

Comment: @Pawan: So, instead of asking the question you have, you ask another question and still hope to get the right answer? We're not mind readers, sorry.

Comment: #define UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINT0(appType, tag, ...) \
    if(NUMARGS(##__VA_ARGS__) == 0)                \
    UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINTx(0, appType, tag, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0,  __FILE__, __LINE__, UPUT_SEQUENTIAL);                  \
else                               \
    UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINTx(0, appType, tag, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0,  __FILE__, __LINE__ , NEXT_ARG(##__VA_ARGS__))
At compilation I am getting error if NEXT_ARG(##__VA_ARGS__) is empty

Comment: @PawanKumarSrivastava: please oh please... edit your question and format this correctly. Comments are not suited for extensive code input :x

Answer (score 0):

Some preprocessors are funny try:

```
#define fun1 fun
```

Or

```
#define fun1(...) fun( __VA_ARGS__)
```

Or

```
#define fun1(x...) fun(x)
```